# Data structure to represent nodes lengths of paths between them?

Tags: java, graph, artificial-intelligence

Okay I am new to Java, and I'm asking this question because I'm sure there is a better simple way to deal with this and the more experienced folk out there may be able to give me some pointers.

I have a graph of cities with lengths of paths between them.  I am trying to construct an algorithm using Java to go from a start city to a destination city, finding the shortest path.  Each city will have a name and map coordinates.  More specifically I will be using the A* algorithm, but that is (probably) not important to my question.

My issue is I am trying to figure out a good way to represent the nodes and the paths between them with the length.

The easiest way I could think of was to create a huge 2 dimensional square array with each city represented by an index, where the connecting cities can be represented by where they intersect in the array.  I assigned an index # to each city.  In the array values, 0's would go where there is no connection, and the distance would go where there is a connection.

I will also have a city subclass with an "index" attribute, with the value of its index in the array.  The downside to this is to figure out which cities have connections, there have to be extra steps to lookup what the city's index is in the array, and also having to lookup which connecting city has the connecting index.

Is there a better way to represent this?

Comment: You can cache the shortest path distance (and the DP array) with Floyd-Warshall algorithm (which runs in O(n ^ 3)), and return the shortest path distance in O(1), and the shortest path in at most O(n). The space used is O(n ^ 2). This assume the graph never changed, or very infrequently.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way would be having a Node structure that store all the pointers to the adjacent nodes.

E.g.

if you have something like this in your data structure

```
   A   B   C

A  /   0   1

B  0   /   1

C  1   1   /
```

in the new structure it would be

```
A: [C]
B: [C]
C: [AB]
```

Compare to your 2D array approach, this way takes longer time to check if two nodes are connected, but uses smaller space

Comment: It only uses less space for sparse graphs. For dense graphs, the overhead for pointers/objects dominates.

Comment: I like this concept.  Wish I could choose two best answers.  The drawing of the structures helps a lot in illustrating how it would work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider...

```
class Node {
  List<Link> link;
  String cityName;
}
class Link {
  Node destinationCity;
  Long distance;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful and simple. I like this.